# How to get first id from the fetched rows in php mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fetching data in php from mysql table. Let say I retrieved 15 rows containing 15 unique ids. Now I want to get the the very first fetched id from the results.

This is what I'm trying..but its giving me the last id

```
    <?php

  $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM orders where Sales_Rep='$sales_rep'");
  while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){ 
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["Order_ID"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Company_Name"]?></td>  
        </tr>
<?php 
        $last_order_date= $row["Order_ID"]; 
        echo $last_order_date;
        } //end of while loop
?>
```

Comment: where is your `while` loop closing ?

Comment: Post the complete code not just part of it please. In order to understand we need to see the entire code.

Comment: you don't need to re-open `<?php ` when you're already inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply add index like this

```
$i = 0;

while loop
    $i++;
    if($i === 1)
        {get ID}
    //rest of your while loop
endwhile;
```

Comment: can you elaborate how can I perform {get ID} ?

Comment: Thanks it woked !

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your sql to

```
SELECT * FROM orders where Sales_Rep='$sales_rep' Order By Order_ID DESC
```

or you use this code

```
    <?php

      $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM orders where Sales_Rep='$sales_rep'");
$i =0;
$first_id = 0;
      while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){ 
if ($i===0){
$first_id  = $row["Order_ID"];}
$i++;
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["Order_ID"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Company_Name"]?></td>  
            </tr>
    <?php 
            $last_order_date= $row["Order_ID"]; 
            echo $last_order_date;
            } //end of while loop
    ?>
```

your first Id is in $first_id